# Error in short excercise in Haskell

Tags: haskell, compiler-errors, functional-programming

I am supposed to write a short code, where I shall figure out if one rectangle and another overlap. Unfortunately, Haskell complains about mismatched brackets. Therefore, I would highly appreciate it if anybody of you could have a short look at my code:

```
  type Point -> (Double, Double)
  type Rectangle -> (Point, Point)
  overlaps:: Rectangle -> Rectangle -> Bool
  overlaps ((x1,y1),(x2,y2)) ((a1,b1),(a2,b2))=(q>=w || t<=z) && (e>=r || u<=i)
                                               where 
                                                            q=min(a1 a2)
                                                            w=min(x1 x2)
                                                            e=min(b1 b2)
                                                            r=min(y1 y2)
                                                            t=max(a1 a2)
                                                            z=max(x1 x2)
                                                            u=max(b1 b2)
                                                            i=max(y1 y2)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Defining a `type` alias is done with `=`, not `->`.

```
type Point = (Double, Double)
```

Also, passing arguments to functions is done as `fun arg1 arg2 arg3 ...`.

So,

```
where q = min a1 a2
      -- etc.
```

By the way, writing `min (a1 a2)` actually means to apply function `a1` to argument `a2`, and then to feed the result as argument to function `min`. This is going to lead to errors since `a1` is not a function, and you want to provide `min` both arguments.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, you're declaring your types incorrectly, they should have an equals sign:

```
type Point = (Double, Double)
type Rectangle = (Point, Point)
```

Second, your formatting seems whack.  I would recommend reformatting with consistent spacing and *not* using tabs.  Configure your editor to insert spaces instead, I see posts on SO every other day where the problem was tabbed indentations, so save yourself the headache and just switch to spaces.  Try formatting your code as

```
type Point = (Double, Double)
type Rectangle = (Point, Point)

overlaps :: Rectangle -> Rectangle -> Bool
overlaps ((x1, y1), (x2, y2)) ((a1, b1), (a2, b2)) = (q >= w || t <= z) && (e >= r || u <= i)
    where 
        q = min a1 a2
        w = min x1 x2
        e = min b1 b2
        r = min y1 y2
        t = max a1 a2
        z = max x1 x2
        u = max b1 b2
        i = max y1 y2
```

Finally, you'll notice that I removed the parentheses from all your `min`s and `max`s, this is because Haskell **does not** use parentheses to pass arguments to a function.  This is not your father's C/C++/Java/C#/Python/whatever.  Haskell only separates arguments by spaces.  Parentheses can be used to put a more complex expression as an argument, e.g.

```
max (x1 + x2) (y1 + y2)
```